# Get parents grandchildren -- Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent-child

```
// I want to reach
<div class="blue flex">
  <div class="upvote"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="url"></div>
    <div class="url_expo"></div>  // to this
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="gone"></div>
    <div class="gone_expo"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="talk"></div>
  <div class="flag"></div>
  <div class="change"></div>  // from this
</div>
```

Actually i already can do that. Homever my way seems really long to me. So i decided to ask if someone can shorten this code.

```
MY WAY
$(this).parent().children().eq(1).children().eq(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way you can do using eq like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('.main:eq(0) > div:eq(1)');
```

Comment: .main:eq(0) indicates to first .main element and div:eq(1) indicates to second div of that .main element.